# Set tags on BoxFile using Box Android SDK v2

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I want to set tags on a file I am uploading using the **Box Android Library v2**. As far as I can tell you can only getTags from a file but there is no API method to set tags on upload or later. The only implementation of **setTag** that I found is in **BoxItemRequestObject** but this interface does not apply to BoxFile or BoxFileUploadRequest.

Below is what I would expect to be able to do, call setTag on the requestObject but there is no such api method available.

```java
File file = new File(filePath);
BoxFileUploadRequestObject requestObject = BoxFileUploadRequestObject.uploadFileRequestObject(folderId.getFolderId(), file.getName(), file);
requestObject.setTag(myTag);
BoxFile boxFile = client.getFilesManager().uploadFile(requestObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/issues/61) on their github repo.

```java
BoxFileRequestObject requestObject = BoxFileRequestObject.getRequestObject();
requestObject.put(BoxFile.FIELD_TAGS, new String[] { "first tag", "second tag"});
boxClient.getFilesManager().updateFileInfo(fileId, requestObject);
```